# How to use two versions of the same JAR in two bundles of OSGi?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, osgi

I have an OSGi setup with maven. 
The parent bundle's pom.xml has a dependency on JAR A which is in turn dependant on JAR B(version 1).
The parent has 2 children bundles. Child bundle 1 uses JAR B with version 1.
Child bundle 2 requires JAR B with version 2.
The JARs are not backward compatible. So I cannot upgrade the version of JAR B from 1 to 2.
I need to use version 1 of JAR in bundle 1 and version 2 of the same JAR in bundle 2, without any errors in class loading.

Right now, I get an error in class loading where any one of the bundles fail due to NoClassDefFound error because of using 2 versions.

How do I resolve this dependency using OSGi?

Comment: Until now you only described your maven setup. In OSGi this is not relevant so much, At runtime in OSGi it is important which Import-Package and Export-Package statements the Manifests contain. Can you add this to your question? Another thing. How do you create the Manifest of your bundles?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I have not added info about JAR B in the Import-Package and Export-Package of both the bundles. But, I have added 'bundle 1' in the Require-Bundle property of bundle 2. Does this impact anything?

Comment: You should not use Require-Bundle. Instead let bnd through maven-bundle-plugin or bnd-maven-plugin do the Manifest writing for you. Embedding the dependency like gjoranv proposed is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages with OSGi (arguably the most important one) is that you *can* use different versions of the same library in different bundles. In the few cases where that's a problem you would either get a 'loader constraint violation' or a 'ClassCastException'. The OSGi troubleshooting doc for the Vespa search engine shows a few [examples](http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/jdisc/osgi-classloading.html#multiple-implementations). This would happen if one of your bundles calls an api in another bundle involving the classes in JAR B (as argument or return value), and the two bundles use different versions of B.

In your case, the problem is that either the failing bundle is missing an Import-Package, and/or there is no bundle exporting the required version of the package with the missing class. You can examine the bundles' `manifest.mf` to verify.

The simplest and safest way to solve this is to embed the desired version of B into each of your child bundles. This way, your child bundles will use their own version of B, living in separate class loaders.

You don't mention how you package your bundles, but if you're using the [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html), it has an [`Embed-Dependency`](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#embedding-dependencies) config option. Please note that you also have to embed the transitive dependencies of B by using the `Embed-Transitive` directive to ensure that all code used inside B is available at runtime.

Another solution is possible if both versions of B are packaged as OSGi bundles, and each exports the package (of the missing class) with a unique version number. (Again, verify from looking at B's `manifest.mf`). Then, you can deploy both B bundles, and have each of your child bundles import the correct version.